# Highlight text by giving it the words you want it to highlight

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to pass in words and create an `<a>` tag and set the attribute style to yellow, basically highlight the text. I'm getting an error on the `words.appendChild(newNode);` Does anyone know how I could create an `<a>` tag with a style on the set words?

```
highlightText(words) {
  // words contains 4 different words.
  const newNode = document.createElement('a');
     newNode.setAttribute(
       'style',
       'background-color: yellow; display: inline;'
     );
     words.appendChild(newNode);
     // words.surroundContents(newNode);
}
```

In the past, this is what I have done but this is using the `window.getSelection()`.

```
 highlightSelection() {
      this.complexWordIdentification(this.postIWant, this.theHardWords);
      const userSelection = window.getSelection();
      if (userSelection.toString() === null) {
         return;
      } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < userSelection.rangeCount; i++) {
            this.highlightRange(userSelection.getRangeAt(i));
            this.word = userSelection.toString();
        }
      }
    }


    highlightRange(range) {
        const newNode = document.createElement('a');
        newNode.setAttribute(
           'style',
           'background-color: yellow; display: inline;'
        ),
        range.surroundContents(newNode);
    }
```

I want to be able to do the same as the function `highlightSelection()` but instead feed in the values that I want instead of highlighting it manually.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: `appendChild` is a function available on a DOM node and it seems it doesn't work with `words` in `words.appendChild(newNode);`. How do you fetch `words`? What does it contain?

Comment: To change word in string to html use `String#replace()` and return html string. Not clear what you are passing in as `words`. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @MihaiT Yes, words is an array of words yes as you stated there, I need to put them into an `<a>` and style it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach:

I have declared the constants for simplicity. You can bring in the words through Network API calls too and pass the words to `highlight` method.

```js
const words = ['Lorem', 'ipsum'];

const getWords = async () => {
 //Use API calls here or simply define pass in Constants
  highlight(words);
}

const highlight = (words) => {
 const high = document.getElementById('highlight')
  const paragraph = high.innerHTML.split(' ');
  let res = [];
  
  paragraph.map(word => {
    let t = word
    if(words.indexOf(word) > -1){ 
      t = '<a class="high">' + word + '</a>'
    }
    res.push(t)
  })
  high.innerHTML = res.join(' ')
}

window.onload = getWords();
```

```css
.high{
  background-color: yellow; 
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div >
  <p id="highlight">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio odio voluptas tempora voluptates expedita quo, nemo sint ipsa similique aliquid doloribus accusamus commodi amet id adipisci eos, inventore in consectetur.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: How could I work around it for angular on the `window.onload = getWords();` trying this out but having the issue there.

Comment: This one replaces all the text that I'm showing and shows the special words, where I want to leave the text in, but highlight the special words. @omkar

Comment: If you could provide some context as to how the current output looks like and what the desired output is. I might help you in a better way. Maybe a jsfiddle link?

Comment: So this is my text: `Hello Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean mHello Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.` It is just some random text. That text is stored in a variable and shown on the HTML with {{ text }} because it's using Angular.  Then i've got a set of special words which I want to highlight, which is stored in another variable called words.

Comment: Made a few edits. This should do the work or @sjahan solution works too.

Comment: I keep getting this error: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null.

Comment: Debug: 1) highlight function is running even before your DOM is loaded. 
2) I'm using highlight as an id to the paragraph tag, use your id accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176072/discussion-between-andrew-and-omkar-keluskar).

Comment: How could I attach the word to the `<a>`, for example now when I click it, I need to know what word I've clicked, so how could I work around that? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small sample :)
You just pass to the function the root element it has to inspect, and then, it's just a basic `replace` function!

```js
const words = ['once', 'you'];

const highlight = (root, words) => {
  words.forEach(word => {
    root.innerHTML = root.innerHTML.replace(word, word => `<a class="highlighted">${word}</a>`);
  });
};

highlight(document.querySelector('.root'), words);
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <p>Let's do a simple test for once.</p>
  <p>Do you like tests?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Would this also work for Angular? the `highlight(document.querySelector('.root'), words);`

Comment: @Andrew yeah, sure why not? It's just a basic JS function, no dark magic here! :) Just watchout: it search for the words in the HTML code, so be sure not to use them in the tags. For example, don't do `...<div class="once">...` if you set `once` in the list of the words you want to highlight.

Comment: @Andrew or set the root the lowest possible, to be sure not to pass the whole page and break things. If you can pass just text nodes, you'll be sure you don't break anything!